# Java maths - testing for NaN

Tags: java, math, nan

I would like to have some kind of project-wide fail fast mechanism (maybe a `RuntimeException`) for any code that causes assignment of `NaN`.

In my project `NaN` is never a valid value.

I realise I could add asserts (using [isNaN](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN())) or other tests throughout but I want to know if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: What are you actually planing to do?

Comment: What **I** would like to do is know exactly where a complicated numerical computation goes wrong, without scattering `isNaN` tests all over the code. In many other environments I can use [IEEE 754 traps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699078/what-languages-expose-ieee-754-traps-to-the-developer), but [not on the JVM](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#35254).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use AspectJ (aspect oriented programming) to throw an error whenever a value is set to NaN.

Essentially, you want to intercept whenever a value is set, and perform some other function.

We've done similar things in our codebase ... but I can't give you much help outside of that.

Answer (score 4):

No - because `NaN` IS a valid value, using it won't cause any exceptions to be thrown.  Without any ubiquitous monitoring mechanisms to use, you would have to test explicitly at the points where it might be assigned or returned from a method.

Answer (score 2):

If you ready to sacrifice the performance of the application, you can create a wrapper for Double (or other numeric object you want to use) and throw exception when `NaN` is set.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it would be possible to create an agent to do this by [instrumenting](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) the code in question to inject *assert* or *if* tests automatically. This would involve a bit of bytecode inspection and transformation (e.g. using *ASM*). In my opinion, it would take extraordinary circumstances to warrant this. You'd have to be careful not to instrument any classes that rely on being able to process *NaN* internally.

I'm not aware that anyone has written such an agent. If you're looking for a silver bullet, I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach - you could integrate code checkers like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) into your build process and create a rule that reports every assignment of `Double.NaN`.

It will not be perfect, because it can't catch NaN's you get from the outside (database, connections) or that someone creates through bit manipulation but at least you can assure that `Double.NaN` can't be assigned to a variable or be used as a method parameter or inside an evaluation.

Defining the rules might be challenging - but at least - it's another approach. The simplest rule could be to forbid `Double.NaN` at all.