# Common underflow and overflow exceptions

Tags: java, exception, overflow, underflow

I am trying to get a hold of overflow and underflow exceptions in java, but couldn't get any nice tutorial. Specifically I wish to learn

1. How are they different from each other?
2. What are the subclasses of these exceptions?
3. In which scenario they are thrown?
4. Which of them can be handled and how?
5. What are the best practice related to them?

Any link to useful tutorial will do

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, any reasons ? Is it dupe, irrelevant, wikifiable.. ?

Comment: I wasn't the person who downvoted you, but, what kind of overflow/underflow are you talking about? Arithmetic? Stack? Something else?

Comment: I wish to get a headstart on these two classes of exception. Any and all will be useful for me

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay, the OP talked about wanting to know about both stack overflow and arithmetic overflow, as well as their corresponding underflow. Here goes....

1. Arithmetic overflow happens when a number gets too big to fit in its value type. For example, an `int` holds values between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1, inclusive. If your number goes over these limits, an overflow occurs, and the number "wraps around". These do not cause an exception to be generated in Java.
2. Arithmetic underflow happens when a floating point number gets too small to distinguish very well from zero (the precision of the number got truncated). In Java, these do not cause an exception either.
3. Stack overflow happens when you call a function, that calls another function, that then calls another, then another...and the function call stack gets too deep. You get a `StackOverflowError` when that happens.
4. Stack underflow doesn't happen in Java. Its runtime system is supposed to prevent that sort of stuff from happening.

To answer the OP's other question (see comments), when you overstep the boundaries of an array, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is issued.

Comment: +1 clear explanation.  I've also heard subtracting one from int.MIN_VALUE called an underflow.  I've not come across your point 2 before.

Comment: @Paolo: I think subtracting one from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is considered an overflow too. But maybe I'm splitting hairs here. :-)

Comment: @Chris Thanks, it helps, where can I get documentation for this stuff ?

Comment: @Ravi: Wow, I'd be hard-pressed to give you specific references at the moment, because a lot of this actually came from personal experience (I've programmed in Java for over 5 years). Hmm. You can (and should) try to read the Java Language Specification, if you're interested in the nitty-gritty.

Comment: @Chris  I was trying hunt it on sun's site but couldn't get what I was looking. I will keep on looking, if I got it will post it here

Comment: Overflow occurs when the number is too big to fit into the type, causing the negative bit indicator to be set, and since Java stores negatives as "two's complement", this will look like a large negative number. Adding 1 to 2147483647 (int max_value) thus becomes -2147483648.

Answer (score 7):

In Java arithmetic, overflow or underflow will **never** throw an Exception. Instead, for floating point arithmetic the value is set as [`Not a number`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), 'infinite' or zero.

To test for these you can use the static methods: [isNaN](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN(double)) or [isInfinite](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isInfinite(double)) using the appropriate wrapper classes. You can handle this as appropriate. Example:

```
double d1 = 100 / 0.;
if (Double.isNaN(d1)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("d1 is not a number");
}
if (Double.isInfinite(d1)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("d1 is infinite");
}
```

For certain operations you can get an [ArithmeticException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html), for example when `dividing by zero` in Integer maths.

I just asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140501/java-maths-testing-for-nan) about a complete project style way to handle this.

Comment: -1 100 / 0 actually returns infinity, not a NaN. Also, an arithmetic underflow (denormal) just returns 0.

Comment: Thanks, I am curios about exceptions like BufferOverflowException and BufferUnderflowException and related stuff

Comment: @Ravi Gupta - please add that to the main question - `BufferOverflowException` and `BufferUnderflowException` is a lot more specific than your original vague "overflow and underflow exceptions" question.

Comment: @Ravi: There is no `BufferOverflowException` or anything like that. Arrays are accessed by index, which, when the index becomes invalid, causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Chris: They have something like BufferOverflowException http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/BufferOverflowException.html

Comment: Oh! Overflowing a `ByteBuffer`. That's something else entirely. Lemme edit my answer. :-P

Comment: @Feast, this is partially incorrect: 'Integer.MAX_VALUE + 2' results in '-2147483647' - No exception but not NaN or infinite or zero either. 'Double.MAX_VALUE * 2' will indeed result in 'Infinity' (which is from a mathematical perspective a pretty wrong answer ;) )

Comment: Thanks, I've "divided" the answer into float and int sections.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no unsigned integers. This makes it easy to throw an Exception, if you think it might be useful.

```
public class Counter
{
  private int counter = 0;

  public int increment ()
  {
    counter += 1;
    if (counter < 0)
      throw new RuntimeException ("Counter overflow");
    else
      return counter;
  }

  public String toString() { return String.valueOf(counter); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very old question, it should be noted that since Java 8, the Math package provides "exact" arithmetic methods which will trigger exceptions when overflow occurs.

e.g.

```
int iv1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int iv2 = Math.addExact(iv1,1);
```

will trigger java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow .