# How to force Java to throw arithmetic exception?

Tags: java, exception

How to force Java to throw arithmetic exception on dividing by 0.0 or extracting root from negative double? Code follows:

```
   double a = 1; // or a = 0 to test division by 0
   double b = 2;
   double c = 100;

   double d = b*b - 4*a*c;
   double x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2 / a;
   double x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / 2 / a;
```

Comment: Isn't the quadratic formula supposed to be divided by 2*a and not 2/a ?

Comment: **Why** do you want to get an exception instead of just checking the outcome? Or was the *actual* problem that you don't know how to check the outcome?

Comment: @DyingCactus: x/2/a == x/(2*a)

Comment: DyingCactus, the thing I wrote ((-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2 / a) is the same as (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140501/java-maths-testing-for-nan

Comment: @BalusC Likely because the exception could have more information about where and how the problem occurred than just "something went wrong here". The underlying hardware very likely has support for trapping these conditions right at the FPU instruction where the NaN appears, but Java does not expose this mechanism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to make Java throw exceptions for these operations. Java implements the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standard for floating point arithmetic, which mandates that these operations should return specific bit patterns with the meaning "Not a Number" or "Infinity". Unfortunately, Java does *not* implement the user-accessible status flags or trap handlers that the standard describes for invalid operations.

If you want to treat these cases specially, you can compare the results with the corresponding constants like [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) (for NaN you have to use the [`isNAN()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN(double)) method because NaN != NaN). Note that you do not have to check after each individual operation since subsequent operations will keep the NaN or Infinity value. Just check the end result.

Comment: just a note: `Double.NaN != Double.NaN` is **true** and `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` is **false**, better use `Double.isNaN(double)`

Comment: It's not true that Java's lack of floating-point exceptions is *because* it implements IEEE 754. The Java virtual machine specifically *[differs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#35254)* from IEEE 754 by not having any way to trap or flag these conditions.

Comment: Fix this answer in light of Jouni's comment, please

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Done. Unfortunately, the link to the JVMS is broken, and I couldn't find where it supposedly says it differs from the spec, so I had to rely on a rather superficial description of the spec behaviour from Wikipedia.

Comment: The Java spec doesn't actually mention traps, but traps (equivalent to Java exceptions) have existed in the IEEE 754 standard since 1985. (That's _before_ Java.) I'm curious why Java doesn't expose them. Interestingly, C# doesn't expose enabling traps either, but will catch them if they're on! https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859645/1151521 Might it work for Java? There is another way that Java differs from IEEE 754. The standard annoyingly doesn't propagate NaNs through min and max, but Java does. (This has been addressed in the 2019 update to IEEE 754, after merely 34 years.)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: I suspect that traps were omitted for reasons of platform independance since the standard merely suggests them as a feature.

Answer (score 4):

I think, you'll have to check manually, e.g.

```
public double void checkValue(double val) throws ArithmeticException {
    if (Double.isInfinite(val) || Double.isNaN(val))
        throw new ArithmeticException("illegal double value: " + val);
    else
        return val;
}
```

So for your example

```
double d = checkValue(b*b - 4*a*c);
double x1 = checkValue((-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2 / a);
double x2 = checkValue((-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / 2 / a);
```

Comment: I don't want to call checkValue every time when division by zero or another "bad" operation may occur. I'd like to surround my code with try-catch and check for failures in one code block, having housekeeping stuff (i.e checkValue() calls) out of the main code.

Comment: @DNNX: the "check in one place" method is supported by `NaN`: When a problem occurs then the end result of your calculation will be `NaN`. Just check for that in the end.

Comment: @DNNX "You can't always get what you want / But if you try sometime, you'll find / You get what you need" (Jagger/Richards) ;)

Answer (score -1):

This code will throw an `ArithmeticException`:

```
int x = 1 / 0;
```

Comment: `System.out.println(1d / 0d);` prints `Infinity`

Comment: My bad: it was integer division that threw the exception.

Comment: It does throw an exception. Good for testing. Thanks.