# Why does division by zero with floating point (or double precision) numbers not throw java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero in Java

Tags: java, exception, arithmeticexception, dividebyzeroexception

The following statement throws `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` as obvious.

```
System.out.println(0/0);
```

because the literal `0` is considered to be an `int` literal and divide by zero is not allowed in integer arithmetic.

The following case however **doesn't** throw any exception like `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`.

```
int a = 0;
double b = 6.199;
System.out.println((b/a));
```

It displays `Infinity`.

The following statement produces `NaN` (Not a Number) with no exception.

```
System.out.println(0D/0); //or 0.0/0, or 0.0/0.0 or 0/0.0 - floating point arithmetic.
```

In this case, both of the operands are considered to be double.

---

Similarly, the following statements **don't** throw any exception.

```
double div1 = 0D/0; //or 0D/0D
double div2 = 0/0D; //or 0D/0D

System.out.printf("div1 = %s : div2 = %s%n", div1, div2);
System.out.printf("div1 == div2 : %b%n", div1 == div2);
System.out.printf("div1 == div1 : %b%n", div1 == div1);
System.out.printf("div2 == div2 : %b%n", div2 == div2);
System.out.printf("Double.NaN == Double.NaN : %b%n", Double.NaN == Double.NaN);
System.out.printf("Float.NaN == Float.NaN : %b%n", Float.NaN == Float.NaN);
```

They produce the following output.

```
div1 = NaN : div2 = NaN
div1 == div2 : false
div1 == div1 : false
div2 == div2 : false
Double.NaN == Double.NaN : false
Float.NaN == Float.NaN : false
```

They all return `false.` Why is this operation (division by zero) allowed with floating point or double precision numbers?

---

By the way, I can understand that floating point numbers (double precision numbers) have their values that represent *positive infinity*,  *negative infinity*, *not a number* (`NaN`)...

Comment: In the first case, since you are using an int, the promotion might result in something like 0.00..001, or something close to Double.MIN_VALUE, which would provide a huge number if you divide anything by it.

Comment: @Tiny: Turn your question around: why does `1/0` throw an exception instead of returning `Infinity`?  The answer is that a two's-complement integer (which is what Java's `int` is) doesn't have any bits available to store special values like `Infinity` or `NaN`, so since the result is not representable in the desired type, an exception has to be thrown.  Floating-point numbers do not have this problem (there is a bit pattern available for `Infinity`), and therefore no exception is needed.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In short, that's the way it's specified in the IEEE-754 standard, which is what Java's [Floating-Point Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) are based on.

> [**Why doesn't division by zero (or overflow, or underflow) stop the program or trigger an error? Why does a standard on numbers include "not-a-number" (NaN)?**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180112211305/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions)
>
> The 754 model encourages robust programs. It is intended not only for numerical analysts but also for spreadsheet users, database systems, or even coffee pots. The propagation rules for NaNs and infinities allow inconsequential exceptions to vanish. Similarly, gradual underflow maintains error properties over a precision's range.
>
> When exceptional situations need attention, they can be examined immediately via traps or at a convenient time via status flags. Traps can be used to stop a program, but unrecoverable situations are extremely rare. Simply stopping a program is not an option for embedded systems or network agents. More often, traps log diagnostic information or substitute valid results.
>
> Flags offer both predictable control flow and speed. Their use requires the programmer be aware of exceptional conditions, but flag stickiness allows programmers to delay handling exceptional conditions until necessary.

Answer (score 19):

It's that way because that's how IEEE 754 defined it.

Division by a floating point 0.0 yields NaN or +/-Inf, depending on whether the numerator is 0 or not.

Division by an integer 0 is not covered by IEEE 754, and generates an exception - there's no other way of indicating the error because an `int` can't represent `NaN` or `Inf`.

Generating an exception is similar to the (software) `INT` generated by a division by zero on x86 microprocessors.

Answer (score 11):

**To Infinity and Beyond**

```
class DoubleDivision {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(5.0/0.0);
    }
}
```

The above code, and the snippets you mentioned gives `infinity`.

Why
Java uses `Double`s to represent decimals. Binary cannot fully represent a number, it can only represent an approximation and therefore, neither can Java’s double.

Imagine a number incredibly close to zero. If you know calculus, imagine a limit at zero. The variable would be approaching zero to some imaginably tiny distance but never equal exactly. You can imagine that, right? Well, suppose that number is needs so much precision for Java to represent, it gives up and calls it `0.0` because it does not have a good alternative. **That’s what is happening here. Any regular number divided by a super close number to zero is basically, infinity**. Try it: `5 / (10^-100)`.

Also refer to section : **Special Floating-Point Values** at [Math Errors](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/idl_html_help/errors12.html) for more info :)

Related question : [why does 1/0 give error but 1.0/0/0 give inf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291606/why-does-1-0-give-error-but-1-0-0-returns-inf)

UPDATE: 
`INT` does not have an infinity and `NaN` value in set whereas float does have a infinity and `NaN` value. (According  to IEEE 754 standards that java follows)

Comment: _Binary cannot fully represent a number, it can only represent an approximation and therefore, neither can Java’s double._ A zero is fully representable in (any?) floating point notation.

Comment: For float/double according to IEEE 754 , there exists a +0 and a -0, we use 0.0 to represent but actually that is simplification/approximation of `1/+-infinity` which as we all know is not `0` but approaches `0`. that is why I said that 0 is not fully representable . I guess some good discussion is coming out of it. :-)

Comment: The point in my comment is that while division by zero may not be well defined (from a strict mathematical view),  and some fractions may be impossible to represent, that may be the case with javas double... but zero _is_ defined and 0.0 == 0 as you expect it to be. So the problem is the division, not the zero. I didn't vote you down btw, someone else did.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин (Hahah) (to tag you I had to go to your profile and copy paste the first letter .. heheh ) 
No aint about the downvote anymore.. yea you are right , the problem is division and not 0.0 , but I guess somewhere I am confusing the concept of floating zero(Math) `1/-+infinity` with float -0.0 and +0.0 (java) 
Not sure.. Confused now :D

Answer (score 5):

When there is a divide by zero, the computer can not create a representation of the result as a number. The computer needs to signal that the result is not a number.

For floating point values it can produce a special not-a-number sentinel value, because there are some 32-bit (for `float`) and 64-bit (for `double`) bit patterns that do not represent a number, and thus can be interpreted as not-a-number (`NaN`).

For integer values using the common twos-complement scheme (as Java requires), all 32-bit (for `int`) and 64-bit (for `long`) bit patterns represent a number. So the computer can not report the problem using a sentinel. It must report the problem "out of band" in some manner. Throwing an exception is the out of band method chosen for Java.

Answer (score 4):

Java follows the IEEE 754 standard which defines values to return by default in the case of a division by zero. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling

> Division by zero (an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0)) (returns ±infinity by default).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Division {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b;
        float result;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value for a : ");
        a = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter value for b : ");
        b = input.nextInt();

        try {
            /* here we used "if clause" because result will be in float
             note: Here result is in float, so JVM Cant Catch Exception.
             if we Try to Divide with Zero with Float Values It gives Output as
             Divided by Zero is Infinity */
            if (b != 0) {
                result = (float) a / b;
                System.out.println("Result of " + a + " divided by " + b + " is : " + result);
            } else // here result will be in integer so Jvm can easily Catch The Exception
            {
                result = a / b;
            }
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry Division By Zero Is Not Possible");
        }
    }
}

/* Ouput :
Enter value for a :2
Enter value for b : 7
Result of 2 divided by 7 is : 0.2857143 */

 /* Ouput :
Enter value for a : 16
Enter value for b : 0
Sorry Division By Zero Is Not Possible */
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for **why** it does so.

Comment: here we used "if clause" because result will be in float
note: Here result is in float, so JVM Cant Catch Exception.if we Try to Divide with Zero with Float Values It gives Output as Divided by Zero is Infinity