# Division by zero in java

Tags: java, integer-division, divide-by-zero

Why is it that division of an integer by 0 gives ArithmeticException whereas division of a non-zero double or float by 0,prints Infinity.
Also division of an int 0 by 0 gives ArithmeticException whereas division of a double or float 0 by 0 gives NaN(Not a number).

```
public class First
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(10/0); //Arithmetic Exception
        System.out.println(10.0/0); //Prints Infinity

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question.See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954429/1638718

Answer (score 1):

java follows IEEE floating point standards/practices, and those incorporate infinity [+ and -] as a value that can be calculated with, and NaN as a representation for results that are not a number.

(And obviously, those *floating point* standards do not have a counterpart for integer arithmetic.)

Answer (score 1):

Division by a floating point 0.0 yields NaN or +/-Inf.

Division by an integer 0 is not covered by IEEE 754, and generates an exception - (i.e because an int can't represent NaN or Inf).