# LibGDX - Sprite from custom class is not showing up

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, sprite

I've been trying to figure this our for like 6 hours now...
I have 2 classes ( `Player` and `UiButton` ), both of them **`extends Sprite`**.
The problem is that the *Sprite* from ***Player* is rendering** and the one from ***UiButton* is not**.

Here, take a look at the code:

**Player.java** ( simplified )

```
public class Player extends Sprite
{
    public Player( float posX, float posY )
    {
        super( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "character/char_idle.png" ) ) );
        super.setPosition( posX, posY );
    }
}
```

**UiButton.java**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

public class UiButton extends Sprite
{
    public UiButton( Texture texture, float posX, float posY, float rotation )
    {
        super( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow.png" ) ) );

        setPosition( posX, posY );
        setRotation( rotation );
    }

    public UiButton( UiButton button )
    {
        super( );
    }

    public void setSize( float toWidth, float toHeight )
    {
        float scaleX = toWidth / super.getWidth( );
        float scaleY = toHeight / super.getHeight( );

        setScale( scaleX, scaleY );
    }

    public boolean isTouched( int touchX, int touchY )
    {
        if( touchX >= getX( ) && touchX <= getX( ) + getWidth( ) )
            if( touchY >= getY( ) && touchY <= getY( ) + getHeight( ) )
                return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

**GameEngine.java** ( not the whole file but the required functions and variables )

```
public class GameEngine extends ApplicationAdapter implements ApplicationListener
{
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Player      player;
    private Sprite      grid;

    private UiButton arrow_right;
    private UiButton arrow_left;
    private UiButton arrow_down;
    private UiButton arrow_up;

    @Override public void create( )
    {
        /** Setting InputProcessor **/
        InitializeInputProcessor( );

        /** Initializing SpriteBatch **/
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( );
        spriteBatch.maxSpritesInBatch = 10;

        /** Creating UI **/
        GenerateUiArrows( 10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) / 4 );

        /** Creating Player **/
        player = new Player( 100, 100 );

        /** Creating background grid **/
        grid = new Sprite( new Texture( generateGrid( 50 ) ) );
    }

    @Override public void dispose( )
    {
        spriteBatch.dispose( );
    }

    public void doUpdating( )
    {
        player.update( );
    }

    public void doRendering( )
    {
        /** Clearing the screen **/
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        /** Beginning SpriteBatch rendering **/
        spriteBatch.begin( );

        /** Drawing background grid **/
        grid.draw( spriteBatch );

        /** Drawing Player **/
        player.draw( spriteBatch );

        /** Drawing UI **/
        arrow_right.draw( spriteBatch );
        arrow_left.draw( spriteBatch );
        arrow_down.draw( spriteBatch );
        arrow_up.draw( spriteBatch );

        /** Ending SpriteBatch rendering **/
        spriteBatch.end( );
    }

    @Override public void render( )
    {
        doUpdating( );
        doRendering( );

        /******************************************/
        /** Here was a loop to control framerate **/
        /******************************************/
    }

    private Pixmap generateGrid( int interval )
    {
        /** Creating temporary Pixmap **/
        Pixmap tempMap = new Pixmap( Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ), Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888 );

        /** Setting lines color to BLACK **/
        tempMap.setColor( Color.BLACK );

        /** Creating horizontal lines **/
        for( int i = interval; i < Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ); i += interval )
            tempMap.drawLine( i, 0, i, Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) );

        /** Creating vertical lines **/
        for( int i = interval; i < Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ); i += interval )
            tempMap.drawLine( 0, i, Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ), i );

        /** Returning the result **/
        return tempMap;
    }

    private void GenerateUiArrows( float padding, float button_size )
    {
        arrow_right = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow.png" ) ), button_size * 2 + padding * 3, padding, 90 );
        arrow_right.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_left = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow.png" ) ), padding, padding, 270 );
        arrow_left.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_down = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow.png" ) ), button_size + padding * 2, padding, 180 );
        arrow_down.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_up = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow.png" ) ), button_size + padding * 2, button_size + padding * 2, 0 );
        arrow_up.setSize( button_size, button_size );
    }

}
```

No errors or warnings are shown. Just UiButtons are not rendered. I haven't setted up OrthographicCamera yet. So it shouldn't be the case either...

Comment: can you post your `arrow.png` image?, I would start with locating your buttons in the same position of your player

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VBW99je.png - the `arrow.png`. And I have tried to set the same position as the player's...

Comment: try remove the rotation or to `setOriginCenter()` before rotating

Comment: tried that as well - still not working :/

Comment: It is working using exactly the same code you added (without player - I've commented that parts). There's some problem with positions but generally rendering arrow. Please show full uiButton class.

Comment: Check my question, I've edited it ( replaced the simplified version of UiButton to full code )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is in **setSize()** method in UiButton class:

```
    public void setSize( float toWidth, float toHeight )
    {
        //System.out.println("super.width = " + super.getWidth() + ", super.height = " + super.getHeight() ); - you can uncomment it to see the super width/height value in the console

        float scaleX = toWidth / super.getWidth( );
        float scaleY = toHeight / super.getHeight( );

        setScale( scaleX, scaleY );
    }
```

Both **super.getWidth()** and **super.getHeight()** returns ZERO (because you haven't set any width/height to the super class object). Then in scaleX/scaleY variables you have **infinity** value - you can see it by uncommenting marked line in my code.

The funny thing is that Java allows you to divide by floating zero - returning mentioned **infinity** value ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not)) and that is why you don't have an Exception there.

**The solution** is to fix this method by calling super.setSize(width,height) or just to delete it at all and lean on default Sprite class setSize() method implementation.

---

One thing more - after fixing the issue you will observe problems with rotation - it is about origin. You can just change you setSize method to

```
    @Override
    public void setSize(float w, float h)
    {
        super.setSize(w,h);

        setOrigin(w/2f, h/2f);
    }
```

and it will do the thing

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day :D It appears I have accidentally overriden setSize( ) method... Once again, thank you for taking care of this!

Comment: Oh and... Is the 90 and 270 degrees oposite in libGDX ? Because 90 degrees should rotate arrow so that it points to right :/