# What decides Nan and Infinity in java division operations

Tags: java, exception, division, dividebyzeroexception

Output of the below code confusing me. Why `NaN` sometimes and Infinity other times ?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    int c = 0; 
    System.out.println(a/0.0);
    System.out.println(a/0);
    System.out.println(b/0.0);
    System.out.println(b/0);
    System.out.println(c/0.0);
    System.out.println(c/0);
}
```

Outputs is:

```
NaN
NaN
Infinity
Infinity
NaN
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

What is the deciding factor here ?

Comment: The Java Language Specification. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2

Comment: That's most likely standardized as per IEEE-754: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954429/14955

Comment: I've seen that you haven't accepted any useful answer. **If one of the asnwers is helpful, accept it by clicking tick below number on the left side**

Comment: Note that `a/0`, `b/0` is going to be identical to `a/0.0` and `b/0.0` respectively: the two operands undergo *binary numeric promotion*, meaning practically that the int denominator is widened to a double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of **The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)** which is a technical standard for floating-point computation established in 1985 by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE).

---

### The purpose:

> The IEEE floating-point standard,.. specifies that every floating
>   point arithmetic operation, including division by zero, ***has a
>   well-defined result***. The standard supports signed zero, as well as
>   **infinity** and **NaN** (not a number). There are two zeroes: +0 (positive zero) and −0 (negative zero) and this ***removes any
>   ambiguity when dividing***.

---

### The Rule:

> In IEEE 754 arithmetic, `a ÷ +0` is **positive infinity** when `a` is
>   **positive**, **negative infinity** when `a` is **negative**, and **NaN** when `a = ±0.`

---

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Comment: This doesn't describe any of the cases involving integers (of which only the last is actually different).