# Java testing divide by zero

Tags: java

I am trying to test the functionality of dividing by zero.

If I just do: `System.out.println(5/0)`, I will get `java.lang.ArithmeticException`

I am trying to test that the exception was thrown.

Here's my unit test:

```
 @Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
    public void given_divideByZeroInput_when_divideByZero_then_verify_throwing_exception() {
        MathClass sut = new MathClass();
        sut.div(10,0);
    }
```

and my `div` is this simple:

```
 public float div(int x, int y) {
        return (float) x/y;
    }
```

However, the unit test is failing, stating:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

What did I do wrong?

I know there are many ways to test the thrown exception, but I am trying to stick with the simple `@Test(excepted = .. )`

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace.

Comment: You're casting x to a float. Thus you're not doing integer division as you're doing in your first snippet, but float division. And the result is thus `Infinity`, not an exception.

Comment: Rather than use `@expected` try using a `try catch` in the test method to catch the expected exception. If that works I would suggest using the `ExpectedException` rule in junit 4 or its junit5 equivalent

Comment: @JBNizet oh yeah, you're right, removing (float) solved it, thanks

Comment: Your code isn’t throwing an exception but the runtime is, so what are you testing here exactly? Not much point in writing unit tests for the java vm.

Comment: If you don't cast your int to float, you will get desired exception. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JB Nizet has found the answer:

> You're casting x to a float. Thus you're not doing integer division as you're doing in your first snippet, but float division. And the result is thus Infinity, not an exception.

But there is something more to explain:

```
    return (float) x/y;
```

means

1. convert `x` to a `float`
2. perform the `((float) x) / y` computation using floating point arithmetic
3. return the value

When you remove the cast:

```
    return x/y;
```

means

1. perform the `x/y` computation using integer arithmetic
2. convert the value to a float (implicitly!)
3. return the value

So there are actually a number of (potential) conceptual errors that might have lead to the mistake that you made.

- A type cast has a higher precedence than `/`.
- An arithmetic operation involving an `int` and a `float` is performed using 32 bit floating point arithmetic.  (The `int` operand will be widened to a `float`)
- Widening also happens in an "assignment context", and a `return` statement is an assignment context.