# Cassandra NodeTool Showing value as NaN

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

In my 3 node Cassandra cluster I tried to get node info by executing "nodetool info" but I can see some NaN values in Cache details.

```
Rack                   : 2a
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 478610, size 36.52 MiB, capacity 50 MiB, 251452781 hits, 292195506 requests, 0.861 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 25 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 18, size 1.12 MiB, capacity 219 MiB, 259 misses, 9648 requests, 0.973 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
```

Can't figure out why it is returning NaN values.

Using Cassandra ReleaseVersion: 3.11.6

Answer (score 2):

It happens because there is no activity in corresponding caches, and as result, hit ratio couldn't be calculated as 0 hits divided by 0 requests gives you a NaN (not a number).  You can see [this discussion about NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not)