# Java division by zero doesn't throw an ArithmeticException - why?

Tags: java, arithmeticexception

Why doesn't this code throw an `ArithmeticException`? Take a look:

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double tab[] = {1.2, 3.4, 0.0, 5.6};

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
                tab[i] = 1.0 / tab[i];
            }
        } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
            System.out.println("ArithmeticException occured!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can I change my code to get an ArithmeticException? (I dont want to change the type of an array to int)?

Comment: This is duplicated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291606/why-does-1-0-give-error-but-1-0-0-returns-inf

Comment: `if (tab[i] == 0) throw new ArithmeticException();`.

Comment: @assylias: Im not so sure about that, I read somewhere that we shouldnt throw an ArithmerticException

Comment: Katie, you are overthinking. :) assylias solution is just fine. If, for some reason, you don't want to throw ArithmeticException, just throw the exception you want.

Comment: @gd1: ok, if you say so ;)

Comment: Checking floating value using `==` is potentially error prone. You should always check against sufficiently small number, to rule out rounding errors.

Comment: I think jnovacho is referring to assylias's comment. When comparing int values, you can use the `==` operator for comparison perfectly fine. But with floats, `0 == 0.0` will return false. You should use the Double Object: `if (Double.valueOf(0.0).compareTo(tab[i]) == 0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does integer division by zero 1/0 give error but floating point 1/0.0 returns "Inf"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291606/why-does-integer-division-by-zero-1-0-give-error-but-floating-point-1-0-0-return)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Why can't you just check it yourself and throw an exception if that is what you want.

```
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            tab[i] = 1.0 / tab[i];

            if (tab[i] == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
                    tab[i] == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
                throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
    } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException occured!");
    }
```

Comment: You need to check for Double.isNaN() as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The man asked why he didn't get an error, he didn't ask how do I do it.

Answer (score 99):

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines `1.0 / 0.0` as Infinity and `-1.0 / 0.0` as -Infinity and `0.0 / 0.0` as NaN.

By the way, floating point values also have `-0.0` and so `1.0/ -0.0` is `-Infinity`.

Integer arithmetic doesn't have any of these values and throws an Exception instead.

To check for all possible values (e.g. NaN, 0.0, -0.0) which could produce a non finite number you can do the following.

```
if (Math.abs(tab[i] = 1 / tab[i]) < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
   throw new ArithmeticException("Not finite");
```

Comment: PeterLawrey: so how can I change my code to get an ArithmeticException? (I dont want to change the type of an array to int)

Comment: @Katie you can check `if(tab[i] == 0.0){throw new ArithmeticException();}` before `tab[i] = 1.0 / tab[i];`

Comment: BTW `0.0 == -0.0` so you don't have to check for two values.

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full, so here a not broken link to the IEEE 754 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/30711

Comment: To check for all special values (i.e. NaN, Infinity, -Infinity), use `if (! Double.isFinite(d))`

Answer (score 26):

That's because you are dealing with floating point numbers. Division by zero returns `Infinity`, which is similar to `NaN` (not a number).

If you want to prevent this, you have to test `tab[i]` before using it. Then you can throw your own exception, if you really need it.

Answer (score 13):

Java will not throw an exception if you divide by float zero. It will detect a run-time error only if you divide by **integer** zero not double zero.

If you divide by 0.0, the result will be INFINITY.

Answer (score 12):

0.0 is a double literal and this is not considered as absolute zero! No exception because it is considered that the double variable large enough to hold the values representing near infinity!

Comment: No, 0.0 really is 0 and the IEEE floating point spec defines the result as a special value "positive infinity", not merely a very large value.

Answer (score 8):

**When divided by zero**

1. If you divide double by 0, JVM will show **Infinity**.

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args){ double a=10.00; System.out.println(a/0); }
   ```

   Console:
   `Infinity`
2. If you divide int by 0, then JVM will throw **Arithmetic Exception**.

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args){
       int a=10;
       System.out.println(a/0);
   }
   ```

   Console: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

Comment: NaN not Infinity :)

Comment: @San4musa That's only for `0/0`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick, Arithmetic exceptions only happen when you are playing around with integers and only during / or % operation.

If there is any floating point number in an arithmetic operation, internally all integers will get converted into floating point. This may help you to remember things easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is behaviour of floating point arithmetic is by specification. Excerpt from the specification, [§ 15.17.2. Division Operator /](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.