# Why RuntimeException doesn't work when you divide by 0?

Tags: java, exception

I wondering to know why this snippet of code has executed without Throwing `RuntimeException`(exactly [ArithmethicException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html)):

**Code:**

```
public class Proba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = new Double(5.0);
        try {
            d = d / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error division by zero!");
        }
        System.out.println("d = " + d);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
d = Infinity
```

I want to know how it is possibly.

My java version is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admintemp>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- ***Why this behavior is possible at Java?***

Comment: Please refer to previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why

Comment: [I'd hope it doesn't throw an error...](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.0POSITIVE_INFINITY)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible because Java follows the IEEE standard for floating-point division.

It is true that integer division by 0 will throw an `ArithmeticException`, but floating-point division by 0 yields a special floating point value for `Infinity`.

To elaborate, [the JLS, Section 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) says:

> [I]f the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

and

> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of
>   IEEE 754 arithmetic:

(snip)

> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed
>   infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

That brings up the question, "Why does IEEE state that it should be
`Infinity` instead of some kind of an error?"  Here's [IEEE's
explanation](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions):

> Why doesn't division by zero (or overflow, or underflow) stop the
>   program or trigger an error? Why does a standard on numbers include
>   "not-a-number" (NaN)? The 754 model encourages robust programs. It is
>   intended not only for numerical analysts but also for spreadsheet
>   users, database systems, or even coffee pots. The propagation rules
>   for NaNs and infinities allow inconsequential exceptions to vanish.
>   Similarly, gradual underflow maintains error properties over a
>   precision's range.
>
> When exceptional situations need attention, they can be examined
>   immediately via traps or at a convenient time via status flags. Traps
>   can be used to stop a program, but unrecoverable situations are
>   extremely rare. Simply stopping a program is not an option for
>   embedded systems or network agents. More often, traps log diagnostic
>   information or substitute valid results.
>
> Flags offer both predictable control flow and speed. Their use
>   requires the programmer be aware of exceptional conditions, but flag
>   stickiness allows programmers to delay handling exceptional conditions
>   until necessary.

Comment: It is only for float point number. What about integer at this case?

Comment: There is no `int` value that represents infinity.  While there is a `float` and `double` representation `Infinity`, there is no such representation for `int` (or `byte`, `short`, or `long`).  Evaluating an `int` divide-by-zero as any other legal, meaningful `int` value would be wrong.  1 divided by 0 isn't `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or anything else representable as an `int`.  Thus Java's only recourse is to throw an exception.