# JUnit does not detect ArithmeticException

Tags: java, junit

I am practicing with JUnit, this is the simple method I want to test

```
public float divide(int a, int b){
      return (float)a/(float)b;
}
```

This is the test (Maths is just a custom class of mine containing that method):

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class )
public void divideByZeroShouldBeDetected(){
    Maths m = new Maths();
    m.divide(2,0);
}
```

Anyway running this test results into a fail...

edit:
ok just checked something "strange", this code actually gives me the exception:

```
float c = 2/0;
```

anyway this one:

```
m.divide(2,0);
```

gives me

```
Infinity
```

and that's the reason why the test fails. So..how to test this behaviour in Junit?

Comment: which Maths class is this?

Comment: a custom class made by me, sorry I am updating

Answer (score 3):

Ok solved....problem was about the type of the paramethers, in this post you can find a complete explaination [Java division by zero doesnt throw an ArithmeticException - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why).

In order to make a Test I just had to assert the returned value was "infinite", this way:

```
@Test
public void divideByZeroShouldBeDetected(){
    Maths m = new Maths(2, 0);
    assertEquals("divide float by zero should be infinity", true, Float.isInfinite(m.divide()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And also,

To clarify, ArithmeticException is thrown only for integers and not for floats.

```
package com.ey.buildmap;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            //System.out.println(3/0);
            System.out.println((float)5/(float)0);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I mean, in the above example, 
System.out.println(3/0);
will throw ArithmeticException, whereas the next line won't as the result will be Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I think your divide method inside Maths class is not correct to pass this test case.

because float number divisible by either 0 or 0.0 is always Infinity.Hence you will never get Arithmetic exception.