# Getting the reciprocal in a number exception in Java

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am creating a Java swing calculator. I want to get the reciprocal of a given number. So if I input 0, it should print out an error message.

Here's my code:

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    double num=0, num2=0;
    String operator;
    JButton bReciprocal=new JButton("1/x");
    JTextField result=new JTextField("0", 25);

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command=e.getActionCommand();
        if(command=="1/x") {
            try {
                num=1/num;
                result.setText(Double.toString(num));
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException ae) {
                result.setText("Math Error");
                num=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I give `0` as the input, what I get is `infinity`. What's wrong with this code? How can I make it show "Math error" instead of `infinity`?

Comment: `command=="1/x"` is not how `String` comparison in Java works, see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why

Answer (score 2):

1.0/0.0 (division of doubles) returns infinity.

You can even see that the definition of `POSITIVE_INFINITY` in the Double and Float classes is :

```
/**
 * A constant holding the positive infinity of type
 * <code>double</code>. It is equal to the value returned by
 * <code>Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L)</code>.
 */
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;

/**
 * A constant holding the positive infinity of type
 * <code>float</code>. It is equal to the value returned by
 * <code>Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f800000)</code>.
 */
public static final float POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0f / 0.0f;
```

If you want an `ArithmeticException` to be thrown, divide integers : 1/0.

Therefore, if you are working with doubles, you don't need to catch that exception. Just add a check that `num != 0.0`.

BTW, you should change `if(command=="1/x")` to `if(command.equals("1/x"))`.

Comment: So if working with doubles division by zero results in infinity.  Exception would occur only if the value is declared as integer?

Comment: @sam_rox Exception would occur if both the divisor and the dividend are int/long and the divisor is 0.

Comment: :This is what I did.And it works finr.Just want to knoew if this is what you told I should do `if(command.equals("1/x")){
   if(num==0){
    result.setText("Math Error");
   }
   else{
    num=1/num;
    result.setText(Double.toString(num));
   }
  }`

Comment: @Eran :Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since IEEE standard for integer arithmetic did not define Integer.NaN unlike `float` or `double`, you need to throw an error when dealing with input of 0 or less

```
if (num <= 0) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input number is is 0");
}
```

Also, you need to [compare Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html) properly using `equals` like `if(command.equals("1/x"))`

Comment: In my other buttons like addition,subtraction I have written as `if(command=="-")` .Should these too need to be changes to `command.equals("-")` likewise. Even with `(command=="-")` the calculations do get performed.Why is that

Comment: @sam_rox: == operator compares the object reference however string literals return true when compared to each other using == operator as they point to the same Object

Comment: So should I change these to `equals()` or is it okay to keep it this way

Comment: Change to equals for sure