# how to solve Arithmetic Exception in java

Tags: exception

Below is my code :

```
public class prg34 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=6;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(a/i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>     at run.prg34.main(prg34.java:8)

How to solve above Arithmetic Exception in java ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why/14138002

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to divide by zero in your first iteration. Change your first condition of i = 0, to something other than zero.

You cannot divide by 0, as I believe Java handles the division by zero error by a processor exception which triggers an interrupt.

Your first iteration is trying 6/0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=6;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println(a/i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first loop in your code gives an exception because you are trying to divide 6 by 0 i.e the ArithmeticException.

In order to fix this you must have to use try catch block. I've illustrated full code here. Please fix this.

```
public class prg34 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=6;
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(a/i);
        }
    }catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Division by zero is not possible. "+ e);
    }
}
```

}