# How can I get an exception from a quadratic formula?

Tags: java

```java
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mavenproject1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a, b, c;
        double x1, x2;
        System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de a: ");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de b: ");
        b = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de c: ");
        c = sc.nextDouble();

        try {
            x1 = ((-b) - (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
            x2 = ((-b) + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
            System.out.println("x1: " + x1 + ", x2: " + x2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Hay un problema");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't got the question. Did you mean in which case you will get an exception ?

Comment: give an example of what is the input you are getting exception of.

Comment: I have to obtain a exception with the Quadratic Formula setting the a with 0 value.
That makes the square root didn't work because the division can't  work with a 0.

Comment: Sorry if my English is not good. Im starting learn.

Comment: See this answer: [Java division by zero doesnt throw an ArithmeticException - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why#:~:text=Java%20will%20not%20throw%20an,the%20result%20will%20be%20INFINITY.)

Comment: Please explain the problem and what kind of solution you're looking for in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetic with `double` values does not throw exceptions.  Nor does taking a square root of zero or a negative number.  So your code going to have to test for specific inputs (or results) and throw an exception explicitly.

Hints:

- read the javadocs for `Math.sqrt(double)` and `Double.isNaN(double)`
- read about what `NaN` means in floating point arithmetic,
- read about √-1 and complex numbers (if you have forgotten your high-school math classes),
- do some algebra to figure out what values cause the quadratic formula to produce complex numbers as the "roots".

Answer (score 0):

B is value to get square root from answer , then you want to throw exception.

Example: √0^2 = 0, then yeah not divisible.

Solution:

> use If-else statement and throw exceptions(custom or default).

//If square root B is 0, then Throw error

```
try {
    if(b == 0){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    else {
    x1 = ((-b) - (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
    x2 = ((-b) + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
    System.out.println("x1: " + x1 + ", x2: " + x2);
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There is A Problem");
    }
```

I replicated It, and this is bonus for you:
https://onlinegdb.com/9oqNMLySU

> Give a thumbs up if it helps. [Gladge](https://cdn.frankerfacez.com/emoticon/509860/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b, c;
    int x1, x2, divisor, dividendo1, dividendo2, raiz, resta, cuadrado;
    System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de a: ");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de b: ");
    b = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de c: ");
    c = sc.nextInt();
    cuadrado = b * b;
    resta = cuadrado - 4 * a * c;
    raiz = (int)Math.sqrt(resta);
    if (raiz==0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
    dividendo1 = -b - raiz;
    dividendo2 = -b + raiz;
    divisor = 2 * a;
    x1 = dividendo1 / divisor;
    x2 = dividendo2 / divisor;    
    System.out.println("x1: " + x1 + ", x2: " + x2);
    
}
```

}

I got it!

Comment: Actually, this solution is incorrect for two reasons.  1) It produces inaccurate results if `sqrt(b^2 -4ac)` is non-integer.  2) The case where `sqrt(b^2 -4ac)` is exactly zero should not throw an exception.

Comment: (Do you understand why you need to cast the `double` to an `int`? What it is actually doing ... in the NaN case?)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).