# How do you enable floating point exceptions for clang in OS X?

Tags: macos, clang++, sigfpe

I want my code to terminate when there is a floating point error. In linux-gcc the "feenableexcept()" function does the job, but that isn't available on in OSX. When using gcc on OS X the approach taken in ([Enabling floating point interrupts on Mac OS X Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247053/enabling-floating-point-interrupts-on-mac-os-x-intel)) works just fine when using gcc, but does not work when using clang.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void handler(int sig) {
  void *array[10];
  size_t size;
  size = backtrace(array, 10);
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
  backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK( ( _MM_EXCEPT_INVALID |
                _MM_EXCEPT_DENORM |
                _MM_EXCEPT_DIV_ZERO |
                _MM_EXCEPT_OVERFLOW |
                _MM_EXCEPT_UNDERFLOW |
                _MM_EXCEPT_INEXACT ) );

  signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
  signal(SIGFPE, handler);

  std::cout<<"Perform 1.0/0.0"<<std::endl;
  double a = 1.0/0.0;
  std::cout<<"1.0/0.0 didn't kill program, result is "<<a<<std::endl<<std::endl;

  int* foo = (int*) - 1 ;// make a bad pointer
  std::cout<<"Attempting to print a bad pointer"<<std::endl;
  printf("%d\n", *foo);
  std::cout<<"Bad pointer didn't kill program."<<std::ends;
}
```

When compiled using gcc5, the result is:

```
Perform 1.0/0.0
Error: signal 8:
0   a.out                               0x000000010f97cb7f _Z7handleri + 28
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff895c652a _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                                 0x00007fff6eab6568 0x0 + 140735050114408
3   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff936a15ad start + 1
```

Wonderful. Works great. However, when compiled using clang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)) the result is this:

```
Perform 1.0/0.0
1.0/0.0 didn't kill program, result is inf

Attempting to print a bad pointer
Error: signal 11:
0   a.out                               0x000000010d501d1f _Z7handleri + 31
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff895c652a _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                                 0x00007fff62b7e568 0x0 + 140734849607016
3   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff936a15ad start + 1
```

Not great. Did not raise the FPE, and the code just kept chugging along. I have looked around, and can't find how to get clang to raise the FPE. Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling floating point interrupts on Mac OS X Intel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247053/enabling-floating-point-interrupts-on-mac-os-x-intel)

Comment: @nwellnhof the approach in the linked question does not work with clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted approach seems to be a new header to a project's built-in includes.  For Linux, this file will be ignored and simply fallback to the stock `fenv.h`.

This code is credit `2009, David N. Williams`, borrowed verbatim from the [`ardupilot`](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/AP_Common/missing/fenv.h) project, which was the first result I could find. I can confirm this works on MacOS 10.13 with `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2`).

**Note:**   Note, although many suggestions I've seen recommend uniquely naming this header for clarity's sake, in many ways it reminds me of a [`polyfill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) (term from JS/webdev), so mimicing that ideology the project the code is borrowed from as well as my own project have kept it names `fenv.h`.  Rename as needed.

**`fenv.h`**

```
#pragma once

#include_next <fenv.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)

// Public domain polyfill for feenableexcept on OS X
// http://www-personal.umich.edu/~williams/archive/computation/fe-handling-example.c

inline int feenableexcept(unsigned int excepts)
{
    static fenv_t fenv;
    unsigned int new_excepts = excepts & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;
    // previous masks
    unsigned int old_excepts;

    if (fegetenv(&fenv)) {
        return -1;
    }
    old_excepts = fenv.__control & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;

    // unmask
    fenv.__control &= ~new_excepts;
    fenv.__mxcsr   &= ~(new_excepts << 7);

    return fesetenv(&fenv) ? -1 : old_excepts;
}

inline int fedisableexcept(unsigned int excepts)
{
    static fenv_t fenv;
    unsigned int new_excepts = excepts & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;
    // all previous masks
    unsigned int old_excepts;

    if (fegetenv(&fenv)) {
        return -1;
    }
    old_excepts = fenv.__control & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;

    // mask
    fenv.__control |= new_excepts;
    fenv.__mxcsr   |= new_excepts << 7;

    return fesetenv(&fenv) ? -1 : old_excepts;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your knowledge. I have tested the above code with MacOSX 10.14 Mojave and g++ in Apple LLVM, but that did not work for me. In contrast, that worked when I tested the above code with g++ v8.3 installed with Homebew. Do you have any idea for making the code working for Apple LLVM?

Comment: @tatsy I have upgraded to Mojave but have not attempted to run the above patch.  If I encounter issues I will provide feedback.  I encourage others to do so as well.

Answer (score 0):

You set the masked exceptions. So you have to clear the bit, if you want to get the exception:

```
_MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK( _MM_GET_EXCEPTION_MASK() 
       & ~( _MM_EXCEPT_INVALID |
            _MM_EXCEPT_DENORM |
            _MM_EXCEPT_DIV_ZERO |
            _MM_EXCEPT_OVERFLOW |
            _MM_EXCEPT_UNDERFLOW |
            _MM_EXCEPT_INEXACT ) );
```

Comment: Pasted this answer into the code, and it didn't work for either g++ or clang++. Did it work for you? Is there a intro level reference that you know of that explains how these bitfields work?

Comment: I typed it in my browser, so I did not test it. Didn't you get exceptions? You can find a reference by googling `_MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK`. What do you mean with "these bitfields work"? In general or in particular to exception masks?

Comment: I didn't get the floating point exception. I have googled _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK, and the approaches that I have found work with gcc, but not with clang. What I mean by "these bitfields work"? is how is the bitfield interpreted? Is there a map of the bitfield? Is it platform dependent, or compiler dependent? I would think that this is something that should be easy to find, but I can't find anything. Perhaps I am just supposed to know this?

Comment: As you know, all values are stored in a combination of bits. Usually these bits are interpreted as an integer or a floating point number. With bit fields every bit is interpreted isolated. Setting or clearing a bit sets resp. clears a specific option. To combine options the bit-or operator `|` is used, to read a specific bit the bit-and operator `&` is used. `~` reverts all bits.